# Best classical statistics books

Tags: p-value, references

This question has been asked many times before but I didnt find great references - so here's another try :)

I am looking for basic statistics book that would be of the level of advanced undergrad. Should go into type I, II error, hypothesis testing, p values, t distr, chi sq testing etc. What would be a great book for that ?

Comment: You can find some good recommendations in [this Quora thread](http://qr.ae/38SDm).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to sharing a nice *collection of books* in the Quora thread that I've referenced in my comment above, I would like to share my **personal selection** of the IMHO top *core statistics* (excluding machine learning, econometrics and other specialized domains) **books** from my extensive Amazon wishlist's *statistical books section* (not sure about some of them being considered "best" or "classical", though). I plan to revamp the **foundation** of my statistical knowledge eventually (I have no formal education in statistics), based on studying these books:

**Probability and General Statistics**

- ["Introduction to probability"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1466575573) by Blitzstein and Hwang (based on Harvard's statistics course);
- ["All of statistics: A concise course in statistical inference"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387402721) by Wasserman;

**Regression and Statistical Modeling Strategies**

- ["Regression modeling strategies: With applications to linear models, logistic regression, and survival analysis"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441929185) by Harrell;
- ["Data analysis using regression and multilevel/hierarchical models"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052168689X) by Gelman and Hill;

**Bayesian Statistics**

- ["Bayesian data analysis, 3rd ed."](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439840954) by Gelman, Carlin, Stern, Dunson, Vehtari and Rubin;
- ["Doing Bayesian data analysis: A tutorial with R, JAGS, and Stan, 2nd ed."](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0124058884) by Kruschke (a more accessible alternative).

Comment: I would add that (great) lectures by Blitzstein are available on youtube: http://youtu.be/KbB0FjPg0mw?list=PL2SOU6wwxB0uwwH80KTQ6ht66KWxbzTIo

Comment: @Tim: That's awesome! Thank you very much for that info and link.

Answer (score 1):

I wholeheartedly suggest

["Introduction to Mathematical Statistics"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321795431) by Hogg, Craig and McKean.

Browse it and you will see it has everything you are looking for and is particularly strong for maximum likelihood theory, sufficiency and hypothesis testing, see chapters 6 to 8.

I have used a number of popular books, such as Casella and Berger, Wasserman, MGB and so on but this is by far my favourite. And although I am a postgrad now, I stil find it immensely useful.